# EF: create new dependent object and assign parent using its property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

## **Question**

As the title implies, I have a parent entity - Customer - and a dependent one - Parcel. They are connected via a one-to-many association. But, the Customer has two lists of Parcel object: currently processing ones and those, which were already delivered to him - CurrentParcels and ArchivedParcels in respect.

Consider the situation, when I firstly create a Customer object and then the Parcel, which I want to be assigned to this Customer. I set the Parcel's attribute "Customer" to the one I have just created. But, how should I determine, to which of the Customer's lists it will be appended, current or archived? Now, it's added to the archived parcels, which, of course, is unacceptable.

I understand, there is a dirty solution - manually remove the Parcel from the archived and then add it to the current, but it does not sound nice. Is there any method to solve this problem?

## **Code Snippets (simplified)**

**Customer and Parcel models**

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Parcel> CurrentParcels { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Parcel> ArchivedParcels { get; set; }
}

public class Parcel
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

**Database context**

```
public class ParcelsManagementDBContext : DbContext
{
    public ParcelsManagementDBContext() : base("parcels")
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(
            new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ParcelsManagementDBContext>());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)
    {
        // Foreign key constraints creation
        mb.Entity<Parcel>()
            .HasRequired(p => p.Customer)
            .WithMany(c => c.CurrentParcels)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.CustomerId);
        mb.Entity<Parcel>()
            .HasRequired(p => p.Customer)
            .WithMany(c => c.ArchivedParcels)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.CustomerId);
    }
}
```

**Client code**

```
public void Code()
{
    var db = new ParcelsManagementDBContext();

    // Add new customers to db
    var cust = db.Customers.Add(new Customer()
    {
        Id = db.Customers.Count() + 1,
        Name = "Foo",
        Email = "1@2.mier"
    });

    // Add new parcel to db with created customer as owner
    var parcel = db.Parcels.Add(new Parcel()
    {
        Id = db.Parcels.Count() + 1,
        Name = "Toys",
        Source = "Pushkina str",
        Destination = "Kolotushkina str",
        Urgency = "high",
        Type = "usual",
        IsConfirmed = false,
        deliveryStarted = false,
        Customer = cust
    });
    db.SaveChanges();
    // So, here cust.ArchivedParcels will contain the parcel, but not the cust.CurrentParcels, if we fetch him from db again
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code where you are fetching data from the database ?

Comment: Parcel has 2 relationships to customer so you need 2 FK and nav properties. CurrentCustomerId, ArchivedCustomerId. Make them both `int?` for optional since it probably can't be both at the same time. Then change your fliuent code to HasOptional.

Comment: As @SteveGreene pointed out. Or add `bool IsArchived` property (column) to the `Parsel` and replace the 2 collections with single `ICollection<Parsel> Parsels`. You can always filter out using the LINQ.

Comment: @SteveGreene and Ivan, thanks for answering, I thought it would be possible to have this configuration, but apparently it wouldn't. I will use the bool property. Thanks again